# Hex-View in IDA [TMS320C3x]

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

For the target processor TMS320C3x, IDA does not display all data in HEX-VIEW as ASCII,
only every 4th byte.
The minimum addressable data block for this target processor is a 32-bit word.
It seems that IDA takes the low byte from the word and prints it as ASCII, and does not use the remaining ones.
How can I fix IDA settings to resolve this issue? Maybe there is some plugin to fix this?

[image: data types]

[image: Hex_View in IDA]

Comment: Which IDA version are you using? Which configuration of the hex view do you see when you right-click on the Hex-View window?

Comment: IDA 7.7, changing Hex-View settings do not effect (i have tried to change text encoding, data format)